# Android Отправка названий найденных bluetooth устройств на сервер

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть необходимость отправить названия всех найденных `bluetooth` устройств на сервер.

Данные в `listadapter` и `listview`, как из них отправить на сервер имена устройств в формате "`BT_name 1, BT_name 2 ...` и т.д". Код:

```
public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BroadcastReceiver discoverDevicesReceiver;
    private BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishedReceiver;


    private final List<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> listAdapter;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, discoveredDevices) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final BluetoothDevice device = getItem(position);
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(device.getName());
                return view;
            }
        };
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    public void discoverDevices(View view) {

        discoveredDevices.clear();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (discoverDevicesReceiver == null) {
            discoverDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();

                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                        if (!discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                            discoveredDevices.add(device);
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        if (discoveryFinishedReceiver == null) {
            discoveryFinishedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    getListView().setEnabled(true);
                    if (progressDialog != null)
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    unregisterReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver);
                }
            };
        }

        registerReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

        getListView().setEnabled(false);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Поиск устройств", "Подождите...");

        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        if (discoverDevicesReceiver != null) {
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("SearchActivity", "Error turn off reciever: " + discoverDevicesReceiver);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Мне нужно их отправить все разом, а не по одиночке. Как отправить я знаю,  мне нужно сформировать формат по указанному выше шаблону из данных в `listadapter`'e.

Comment: Сформировать формат?

Comment: при формулировке "взять данные с listview" Вы далеко не продвинитесь. Потому что в listview данных нет. Он только отображает то, что ему отдает адаптер. Поэтому, нужно смотреть, где данные берет адаптер и оттудовать сформировать к примеру json (или xml. Или на крайний случай обычный текстовый файл)

Comment: @KoVadim Да, я ошибся, в теме вопроса указал я что данные в адаптере. Данные адаптер берет от bluetooth.startDiscovery.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, данные из  адаптера сформировать по шаблону так чтобы одним запросом отправить

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky обновил вопрос, добавил код. Как мне отправить на сервер названия всех найденных устройств разом?

Comment: При чем тут вообще адаптер и listview, если ваши устройства харнятся в discoveredDevices? Сериализуйте этот список и отправляйте. Некорректный вопрос.

Comment: @YuraIvanov как мне это сделать?

Comment: Ну например, добавьте кнопку, создайте для нее обработчик клика, в цикле по discoveredDevices сформируйте строку конкатенацией, отправьте ее.

Comment: @YuraIvanov  я реализовал формирование json из массива discoveredDevices, и его отправку,  но отправляет он Mac адреса, а мне нужно названия устройств, как здесь быть?

Comment: Если у вас есть другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно (предварительно самостоятельно попытавшись решить задачу, почитать документацию). То, о чем вы спрашиваете в комментарии никаким образом не соотносится с текстом вопроса.

Comment: @YuraIvanov по теме вопроса это относится, мне помогли и я реализовал отправку и формирование json, но отправляется Mac адрес, а как указанно в вопросе нужно отправить названия устройств. Документацию читал но на понимание многого банально не хватает опыта. Мне примерами легче понять (не готовыми решениями, а примерами)

Answer (score 1):

У `BluetoothDevice` есть `getName()`

Что вам еще нужно?

```
StringBuilder deviceNames = new StringBuilder;
for(BluetoothDevice device: discoveredDevices)
    deviceNames.append(device.getName()+",");
```